# Phoenix Rendering 404 and 500 as JSON

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I started a phoenix project without using the `--no-html` option, and am now trying to ensure that the `404` and `500` errors render as JSON. The project started on Phoenix `1.1.0`, and has been updated to `1.1.4`.

I've modified the `config/config.exs` file's `render_errors` (under `config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint`) to be `[view: MyApp.ErrorView, format: "json", accepts: ~w(json)]`.

The routes all accept JSON and currently none of them accept HTML.

I've modified the `web/web.ex` file to remove the use Phoenix.HTML in the `view` function, and I've modified the `web/views/error_view.ex` to render JSON.

However at this point both `404` and `500` errors still return html.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you update your `config.exs`?

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  # ...
  render_errors: [accepts: ~w(html json)],
  # ...
```

And what kind of html is returned? Maybe it is the phoenix debug page for your dev environment which you can disable in `config/dev.exs`

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  # ...
  debug_errors: false,
  # ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I updated my `config/config.exs` as noted in the original post. Upon closer inspection it's the phoenix debug page for the dev environment, thanks for pointing that out.

But changing the `debug_errors` to `false`, doesn't appear to have changed that in the dev environment.

Comment: But running it in the `prod` environment things seem to be working out. So I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Scratch my comment about `debug_errors` not working in dev. I had set it in my `config/config.exs` rather than my `config/dev.exs` which was overriding it.